# Will there be functions if there were no stacks?

Tags: compilation, computer-science, cpu-architecture

I know that a stack data structure is used to store the local variables among many other things of a function that is being run.

I also understand how stack can be used to eleganlty manage recursion.

Suppose there was a machine that did not provide a stack area in memory, I don't think there will be programming languages for the machine that will support recursion. I am also wondering if programming languages for the machine would support functions without recursion.

Please, someone shread some sight on this for me.

Comment: you could always have the compiler "manually" use an area of memory as a stack-like data structure.  You can emulate push/pop and call/ret on x86 using a register other than RSP, using just MOV loads/stores, ADD, and indirect JMP.

Comment: Also, I seem to recall reading an SO answer about languages that implement function call / ret by passing around pointers instead of pushing a return address.  Or something, I really don't remember this.  It wasn't just a link-register equivalent of pushing a return address, it was something different.  But I can't remember enough to find it again or say anything useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit of theoretical framework is needed to understand that recursion is indeed not tied to functions at all, rather it is tied to expressiveness.
I won't dig into that, leaving Google fill any gaps.

---

Yes, we can have functions without a stack.

We don't need even the *call/ret* machinery for functions, we can just have the compiler inline every function call.
*So there is no need for a stack at all.*

This considers only functions in the programming sense, not mathematical sense.
A better name would be routines.
Anyway that is a simply proof of concepts that functions, intended as reusable code, don't need a stack.

---

However not all functions, in the mathematical sense, can implemented this way.
This is analogous to say: "We can have dogs on the bed but not all dogs can be on the bed".

You are in the right track by citing recursion, however when it comes to recursion, we need to be a lot more formal as there are various forms of [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursively_enumerable_language).

For example in-lining every function call may loop the compiler if the function being inlined is not constrained somehow.
Without digging into the theory, in order to be always sure that our compiler won't loop we can only allow [primitive (bounded) recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function).

What you probably means by "recursion" is [general recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C-recursive_function), that cannot be achieved by in-lining, we can show that we need an infinite amount of memory for GR and that is the demarcation between PR and GR, not having a stack.

---

So we can have function without a stack, even recursive (for some form of recursion) functions.

If your question was more practical then just consider [MIPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_instruction_set).
There is no stack instructions or stack pointer register in the MIPS ISA, everything related to stack is just convention.
The compiler could use any memory area and treat it like a stack.